# Is there a synonym for "young adult"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am a little confused about the difference between a definition of "young adult" vs the list of synonyms that come up in a thesaurus.

The [definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/young-adult) of "young adult" is generally a late teen to early twenty or someone in the early years of adulthood. Yet in the [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/young%20adult) [there](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/young_adult.html) are synonyms such as juvenile, adolescent, minor etc, all of which clearly point to ages younger than adulthood. In my opinion none of these are true synonyms in the same way that gray/grey is not a synonym for black.

My question then is, is there a single word synonym for young adult? I had been using [youth](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/youth) before but realised that it appears to mean either an adolescent or young adult and is therefore a bit too vague? Looking forward to a second opinion on the above.

Comment: There are vanishingly few, if any, true synonyms.  And I'd say no simple terms overlap too well with 'young adult'.

Comment: *Young adult* is often synonymous with teenager, even when in the minor years. Young Adult fiction, for instance, is aimed at readers [*between the ages 12 and 18*](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/whats-the-difference-between-middle-grade-fiction-vs-young-adult-fiction#quiz-0). So I would say using *young adult* to refer to actual legal adults is a very rare usage.

Comment: Note that the link you provide gives _two_ definitions for 'young adult'. Obviously the literal meaning is a person in the early years of adulthood, but in recent times the phrase has been adopted to describe fiction written for teenagers.